# Perl module - dist.ini and platform specific prereqs

Tags: windows, perl, perl-module, dist-zilla

**How can I add conditional prereqs to `dist.ini` for each platform (Windows/Non windows) I want the module to support?**

For example in perl code I could do:

```
if ( $^0 eq 'MSWin32' ){
    require Win32::Foo;
}else{
    require Bar::Baz;
}
```

How do I cater to each system/platform like this in `dist.ini` so that the proper prereqs are installed via cpan/cpanm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it in `dist.ini`, since an ini file doesn't really have any way to do conditional logic. But one way might be to write your own Dist::Zilla plugin, something like this:

```
package Dist::Zilla::Plugin::MyPrereqs;    # pick a better name

use Moose;
with 'Dist::Zilla::Role::PrereqSource';

sub register_prereqs { 
    my $self = shift;

    my %prereqs;
    if ( $^0 eq 'MSWin32' ) { 
        $prereqs{'Win32::Foo'} = '0.12';     # min. version
    } else { 
        $prereqs{'Bar::Baz'} = '1.43';
    }

    $self->zilla->register_prereqs( %prereqs );
}
```

If you generalize this to take some platform-dependent lists of prereqs within `dist.ini`, it would make a good CPAN release.

Comment: I'll check this out, I found [Dist::Zilla::Plugin::OSPrereqs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::OSPrereqs), but I'd have to add in each OS, rather than just windows/non windows. I'll test this and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Dist::Zilla::Plugin::OSPrereqs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::OSPrereqs). For your example it would look like:

```
[OSPrereqs / MSWin32]
Win32::Foo = 0.12

[OSPrereqs / !MSWin32]
Bar::Baz = 1.43
```